# Visual Studio Code : Select a language to get started. Start typing to dismiss, or don't show this again

Tags: settings

I appreciate if you could help me with such silly question.
I used to have a line prompting me to choose a programming language whenever a new file is created in 'visual studio code'. By mistake, I clicked on don't show and, now,  I need to return it back!.
Do you have any idea how to display it again.
The line is saying
"Select a language to get started. Start typing to dismiss, or don't show this again."
It is the first line appears in the created new file.

I tried to search the settings, but I got lost.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can enable it via File | Preferences | Settings. Then search for "untitled".

You should find it under Workbench>Editor>Untitled:hint. Change from "hidden" to "text".

Comment: Thank you very much. It is the one I need.

Comment: This isn't working for me :( I've set the setting as instructed but still not seeing the "Select a language to get started. Start typing to dismiss, or don't show this again" prompt. Leaving this comment in here in case anyone else has the same problem and perhaps figures it out. Let me know if you do.

Comment: In recent vscode, "untitled" is now apparently called "empty" in the config menus.